# Strings in c programming

Tags: c, string, pointers, initialization

why am i unable to compile the program containing the code

```
char name[10];
name= "Rajesh";
```

While i am able to compile a program with

```
char name[10]="Rajesh";
```

Answer (score 10):

That's because your code snippet is not performing *declaration*, but *assignment*:

```
char name[10];  // Declaration 

name= "Rajesh"; // Assignment.
```

And arrays are not directly assignable in C.

The name `name` actually resolves to the address of its first element (`&name[0]`), which is not an [lvalue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29), and as such cannot be the target of an assignment.

***String Variable Declarations and Assignments***

*String variables can be declared just like other arrays:*

```
char phrase[14];
```

*String arrays can be initialised or partially initialised at the same time as being declared, using a list of values enclosed in "{}" braces (the same is true of arrays of other data types). For example, the statement*

```
char phrase[14] = {'E','n','t','e','r',' ','a','g','e',':',' ','\0'};
```

*both declares the array "phrase" and initialises it to the state. The statement*

```
char phrase[14] = "Enter age: ";
```

*is equivalent. If the "14" is omitted, an array will be created just large enough to contain both the value ""Enter age: "" and the sentinel character "'\0'", so that the two statements*

```
char phrase[] = {'E','n','t','e','r',' ','a','g','e',':',' ','\0'};
char phrase[] = "Enter age: ";
```

*are equivalent both to each other and to the statement*

```
char phrase[12] = "Enter age: ";
```

***However, it is important to remember that string variables are arrays, so we cannot just make assignments and comparisons using the operators "=" and "==". We cannot, for example, simply write***

```
phrase = "You typed: "; //Wrong way
```

*Instead, we can use a special set of functions for string assignment and comparison.*

**Edited :**

*And other way is to do that, using pointer : -*

*Declare variable*

```
char const *phrase;     /* a pointer to type character */
```

*And initialize variable as where you want, as*

```
phrase = "Test string";
```

Comment: +1 excellent answer, however, I think a lot of coufusion could be avoided if we just didn't use the word "string" with respect to arrays of characters in C. C simply does not have a "string" data type - just an array of characters, a convention with respect to how these arrays are constructed (ie. ends with a null) and a bunch of runtime routines to maniplate arrays following this convention (eg strcpy).

Comment: I was tempted to write the pointer example, but then I thought I was opening a can of worms. The `pA` now is "pointing" to a string literal that mustn't be modified (and that sadly sometimes *can* be modified). Without even thinking about the implicit conversion `char[] => char*` and "what are the difference between `"Enter age: "` and `"Test string"`?

Comment: BTW, I think you need to declare `char const *pA;` for it to work - otherwise you're losing constness from the string literal.

Comment: @Useless Sadly for historical reasons (retrocompatibility with old code), `*pA` *can* be a `char*`

Comment: Although it may SEGV if you try writing to your allegedly non-const `char*` ;-)

Comment: @Useless I couldn't understand your comment.

Comment: It's OS-dependent, and I hit the same thing when I first started using UNIX.  Because string literals are stored in read-only memory (in all the UNIX variants I've used), writing into them triggers a segment violation (SEGV) and crashes the process.  Previously I'd used MS-DOS and it didn't protect the initialized data segment from being written.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot assign values to string arrays by using assignment.
In C, You can only initialize arrays not assign them, a array of characters is no exception for this rule.

You will need to use string copying functions like `strcpy` or `strncpy` and so on.

However you can encapsulate a string in a struct and simulate this:

```
typedef struct Yourstring Yourstring; 
struct Yourstring 
{ 
    char a[24]; 
};  
Yourstring a = { "abcd" }; 
Yourstring b = a; 
Yourstring c = { 0 }; 
c = b;
```

Comment: I think you should explain him better. explain him the difference between `char name[10]` and `char*` and the differences that there are.

Comment: i'll add this as a comment: your first choice is a mix between C (first statement) and C++ (second statement). this link should be useful to have some comparisons http://cs.smu.ca/~porter/csc/ref/c_cpp_strings.html

Comment: Be careful - copying structs in this way is not possible with all C compiler implementations.

Answer (score 3):

```
char name[10];
```

In this first example, you're declaring `name` to be an array of ten characters.  The symbol `name` is now interpreted as the starting address of this array, but while you can write *into* the array, you can't move the symbol `name`.
So, this:

```
name= "Rajesh";
```

would mean pointing `name` away from the array you declared and at the location of the string literal `"Rajesh"` which is stored elsewhere in memory.  You just can't do this.

What you *can* do is either:

```
strcpy(name, "Rajesh");
```

which copies your string literal from it's immutable location in your executable, into the char array you declared, or:

```
char const *pointer_to_name = "Rajesh";
```

which doesn't copy anything, but merely stores the address of your immutable string literal into a variable where you can use it, or your second example:

```
char name[10]="Rajesh";
```

which declares `name` to be an array of 10 characters *and initialises it*.

Comment: I really feel I should warn you to be careful of `strcpy` as well, but the post was long enough.  However: **be careful of `strcpy`**. It doesn't check the destination is big enough for the string, and you can easily cause problems if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
char name[10];
name= "Rajesh";
```

Here `name` is an array of characters.
The simple `name` is basically pointer to first element of array and it cannot be assigned with some value like it's done in above statement.

My point is

char name[10];
name= "Rajesh";

Explanation:
This is not the correct declaration of array. Strings are nothing but collection of characters terminated with '\0' operator. So, the array index (which in this case is **'name'**, basically points to address of 1st character in array i.e name holds the address of character 'R' in 'Rajesh'.

[image]

If you want to initialize like as mentioned above, the better approach could have been:

char name[10];
*name= "Rajesh";

Now, the above declaration won't throw any error, but still it will throw warning, like:

assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
*name = "Rajesh"

Comment: *The simple `name` is basically pointer to first element of array* NO, this is a confusing analogy: `name` is the name of the array. Arrays cannot be assigned to with `=`. If `name` was a pointer, Any valid pointer value could be assigned to it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your rephrased answer is still confusing: `name` does not *point* to address of first character, it does not *hold* the address of character `R` in `Rajesh`, it **is** the address of that character. `name` is not a pointer at all, it is the array itself. Furthermore the syntax `*name = "Rajesh"` may be more readable as `name[0] = "Rajesh"`, which makes it obvious that one is trying to store a string into a character. It is a shame C compilers accept this nonsense with just a warning, it should be an error.

Answer (score 0):

AS `char name[10]="Rajesh"` is definition compiler understands what are you trying to do and corrects your mistake. In c++ strings written in "" are constant and some compilers put them to stringpools to save space. `name="...."` means that you are trying to assign a constant to a non-constant pointer which is not allowed.

you should use strcpy to copy a string into an array.

Comment: I think @xanatos is more correct here: array initialization is a permitted special case.

Comment: Well when you compile it on VS you will get 'error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [6]' to 'char [10]'' which obviously is an const/non-const assignment problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
char name[10] ="Rajesh";
```

This one is an array initialization. The compiler knows of it. It's a one-shot trick. You can use it only when you define your variable. It would be equivalent to:

```
char name[10] = { 'R', 'a', 'j', 'e', 's', 'h', '\0' };
```

The other one is illegal, because **you can't use array initialization outside of array definition**.

Answer (score 0):

I dont remember where exactly i read it but C standard says, you can assign a string value for an array at the defination but not after the defination.

```
char a[10]="rajesh" its a defination hence works
char a[10];a="rajesh"; fails its not a defination
```

rather you need to use strcpy(a,"rajesh") to assing a value for a string, if its not a defination